# Array of routes in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In [NG Docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route) it says that the routes prop of $route returns Array of all configured routes, however what I get from it is (`console.log($route.routes)`):

[image]

Which not only it's not an array but also shows two keys for each route, one for controller and one for new.

How can I get a sample array for routes without doing manipulation on this property so I can generate my nav based on `route in routes`.

Basically a hassle free way to get `["/home", "/about", ...]` like a peach

I would like to avoid converting this into array and removing the keys to end up with what I want. Unless an NG ninja here says I have no other choice.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs are apparently outdated, as they say that `$route.routes` will be an array, but it obviously is an object.  So the only real way to get an array would be to do the conversion you were talking about.  The reason there are two entries in the object for every route is because both `/about` and `/about/` are valid paths for the `/about` route.  To simplify any ambiguity, Angular adds entries for all routes with a trailing `/` and then redirects to the route without the trailing slash.

When doing your conversion, you only want the original routes (without the trailing slash), which should be all of the routes in the object that have a `.controller` property.

So something like:

```
var routes = [];
angular.forEach($route.routes, function(route, key){
    if(route.controller) routes.push(route.originalPath);
});
// routes should now be ["/about","/home","/login"]
```

Sorry that's not the answer you wanted, but its probably the only way to get what you need.  Hope that at least points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks mate. If I have no choice then sure :) Would be nice if they expose this simply via $routes. Who doesn't want a nav!

Comment: Just for info - documentation has been updated to the correct type of `$route.routes`